# Classpath in Ant build file

Tags: xml, ant

I'm trying to make an Ant build file for my JBoss AS 7 project. The build file is supposed to build my project into an EAR. I was getting the following errors so I assumed the classpath is being overlooked somehow (please correct me if I'm wrong).

```
C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\build-handmade.xml:21: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 4 source files to C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\build

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:4: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.*;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Entity
@Entity

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Table
@Table(name="schemas")

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol: class SequenceGenerator
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_schemas", sequenceName = "")

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:7: package javax.ejb does not exist
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:8: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:9: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\interfaces\GrahamsProjBeanLocal.java:3: package javax.ejb does not exist
import javax.ejb.Local;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\interfaces\GrahamsProjBeanLocal.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Local
@Local

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\interfaces\GrahamsProjBeanRemote.java:3: package javax.ejb does not exist
import javax.ejb.Remote;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\interfaces\GrahamsProjBeanRemote.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Remote
@Remote

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Stateless
@Stateless

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class EntityManager
location: class grahamsproj.session.delegate.GrahamsProjBean
EntityManager em;

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Id
location: class grahamsproj.entity.Schemas
@Id

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Column
location: class grahamsproj.entity.Schemas
@Column(name = "ID")

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\entity\Schemas.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GeneratedValue
location: class grahamsproj.entity.Schemas
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_schemas")

C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\src\grahamsproj\session\delegate\GrahamsProjBean.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PersistenceContext
location: class grahamsproj.session.delegate.GrahamsProjBean
@PersistenceContext

17 errors
C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\build-handmade.xml:21: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So now my build file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/NZWmQEjN (too long to post in here). As you can see I put in a classpath part. But now I'm getting this error:

```
C:\workspace\LearningAS7\GrahamsProj\build-handmade.xml:11: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my build file?

Comment: it mostly depends what is referenced by the variable third-party_jars that is probably defined in build-impl.xml...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
<classpath>
     <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
      <fileset dir="lib">
           <include name="**/*.jar"/>
       </fileset>
       <pathelement location="classes"/>
       <dirset dir="${build.dir}">
           <include name="apps/**/classes"/>
           <exclude name="apps/**/*Test*"/>
       </dirset>
       <filelist refid="third-party_jars"/>
  </classpath>
```

However, you can't simply toss `<classpath>` out by its lonesome self.

What you're doing is creating a ***PATH*** that can be used as a ***CLASSPATH*** somewhere else. You probably want:

```
<path id="class.path">
     <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
      <fileset dir="lib">
          <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <pathelement location="classes"/>
      <dirset dir="${build.dir}">
          <include name="apps/**/classes"/>
          <exclude name="apps/**/*Test*"/>
      </dirset>
      <filelist refid="third-party_jars"/>
</path>
```

Now, you can use that ***PATH*** when you need to specify the classpath:

```
   <javac srcdir="${src}"
        destdir="${build}"
        classpathref="class.path"/>
```

Or...

```
   <javac srcdir="${src}
        destdir="${build}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="class.path"/>
        </classpath>
   </javac>
```

The last one lets you add multiple classpaths if required, and some people prefer it because it makes it easier to change the classpath when required.

Comment: My problem is I don't know what each of those commands do. I looked up the ANT command reference and `path` is not in there. Plus some of the others aren't in there. Do you know of a reference that explains them?

Comment: @Graham You're probably looking only at the [task reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html). Path is located in the [Concept and Types](http://ant.apache.org/manual/conceptstypeslist.html) under [Path Like Structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path). You should also check out the [Reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#references) section which tells you about how you can define something like a Path, Fileset, etc, and reference it later on. Note you define with the `id` parameter, but reference it with the `refid` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, those are a big help. Also, I made the change that you suggested but I am still getting the same errors. Something else must be going on. I copied and pasted that block of XML for the classpath from a tutorial so it is not specific to my project. Also, what does the `**` and `*` mean in the name attributes?

Comment: Java errors are like a car crash. Someone runs a stop sign, someone hits that person, they careen into another car which bounces off of a lamp post. You have a big mess, but it's really the first error that caused the whole reaction. Your first error is _package javax.persistence does not exist_. Solve that, and the undefined errors will go away. There might be more, but handle one error at a time. The question is where this class is defined. I believe it should be defined in an Oracle JAR which should be something like `ojdbc.jar`. Is this in your classpath?

Comment: Update your pastebin with the newer version of your build.xml. I'd like to see the changes you've made.

Comment: Here is my latest one. http://pastebin.com/kG2gTPPk Does it look like I have the classpath setup right? I have the pathelement looking at the src classes then a fileset for all my libraries. When it goes to the MyDeploy target it is having trouble finding the application.xml. This is probably just a problem with the location I have for appxml. Also, how should I include the persistence.xml in the EAR?

Comment: It looks like you're defining and using `class.path` correctly. Do you still get that non-existent package error? Make sure that there's a jar in your `${basedir}/lib` directory that contains that _package_. Early version of Oracle used a zip file instead of a jar file, so specifying `<include names="*.jar"/>` would skip that one. No need to have `${src}` in your classpath. See the examples on the bottom of the [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) page to see how you can include other files, etc. in your ear. You're only including your one jar you built.

Comment: No, I no longer have the error. The jar is not being built for some reason though. I don't see anything wrong with what I have in the compile target. Do you? Also, this is an EJB project with a database it needs to connect to. I am deploying the EAR into JBoss AS 7.1 and it contains an entity bean, session bean, and two interfaces. So is persistence.xml necessary?

Comment: There's no `<jar>` task. All you have is an `<ear>` task which is going to the directory where you built all the `.class` files, but only zipping up files that end with `*.jar` suffix which is none. You should have an ear file that's practically empty.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out yesterday. I should have done more research before asking. The ear looks good to me now but I am getting a bunch of errors in JBoss 7.1 when I start it up. I'll google the errors and see what I can find. If I have no luck I'll just create another question. Thank you for all your help.